# Multiple Field separators with AWK

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I'm trying to separate the ifconfig and give me the output just the current IP, broadcast, and netmask. The problem I'm running into is that the output is in spaces and in colons. I must be missing something, because I can't seem to get around this part. It doesn't seem that my OFS statement is working.

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F ':' 'BEGIN{OFS=" ";}{print $2}'
```

Outputs this:

```
127.0.0.1  Bcast
```

The above is the IP of the unit. I really just want it to output

```
127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some easy solutions:

```
ifconfig eth0 | tr : \  | awk '/inet addr/{ print $3 }'
```

and

```
ifconfig eth0 | tr -s \  | awk '/inet addr/{print $4 }' FS=':| '
```

also:

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{print $13 }' FS=':| '
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you will always have a static string, then maybe just a substitution will work for you?

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{ sub(/addr:/, "", $2); print $2; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sed:

```
ifconfig eth0 | sed -n '/inet addr/{s/[^:]*:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p}'
```